# Check if style="height: 0px"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few elements with inline styling height assigned via a script. I need to check is an element has the following: `style="height: 0px"`

```
<div class="myEm" style="height: 30px">...</div>
<div class="myEm" style="height: 10px">...</div>
<div class="myEm" style="height: 0px">...</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".myEm").each(function(){
   if ($(this).attr("style") == "0px") {
      $(this).css("border-color", "red");
   }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p9nfskeL/1/

Comment: If the height can be `0`, why are you setting `min-height: 10px`? I thnk that's what causing the problem. Also, why not just hide the element?

Comment: Well it's not causing _this_ problem, but I can see it causing a problem with what you're trying to do. https://jsfiddle.net/2qb4g6as/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the exact code you have and you cannot modify any HTML, than you can do a string comparison here..

```
$(".myEm").each(function() {
  if (this.style.height == '0px') {
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
  }
});
```

The issue is, you have set `min-height` to `10px` which is in action, so though you have `0px` defined as inline, it won't override your CSS as `min-height` is defined separately. So either you need to call `min-height: 0;` inline or you can check like above. Note that the `.height()` will always return `10` so am using `this.style.height` to get the value you have declared inline and not the one which is being rendered.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/py9f4o8d/)

---

Note that if the HTML is exact as you've shared, you can also achieve the above like

```
.myEm[style="height: 0px"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gphvtLdk/)

Comment: FYI, writing `$(this).get(0)` is functionally identical to writing `this` here

Comment: yup, but I read the OP wanted the "jQuery" way and since @Rupinder already answered, so I wanted to provide some different syntax which is fine too..

Comment: sure both are fine and work the exact same way, but if you want to access the `style` property on `this` then it seems quite useless to wrap it in a jQuery selector and then access the first (and only) item in the selector array.

Comment: @ChrisBarr hmm, makes sense, let me change it :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following works:

```
$(".myEm").each(function() {
  if (this.style.height == "0px") {
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
  }
});
```

Comment: It does. Is there any way not to mix jQuery with standard JS?

Comment: if ($(this).attr('style') == 'height: 0px') { will also work but use at your own discretion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your height is never 0 because you have `min-height: 10px` in your css.
2. You can directly use $(this).height instead of accessing the style object. It gives a numeric value and you can do a NOT check as shown.

Hope this is helpful!

```js
$(".myEm").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).height())
  if (!$(this).height()) {
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
  }
});
```

```css
.myEm {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myEm" style="height: 30px">...</div>
<div class="myEm" style="height: 10px">...</div>
<div class="myEm" style="height: 0px">...</div>
```